# INTERSECT in MySQL Using Comparable Columns

Tags: mysql, intersect

I would like to create an INTERSECTion of the following two queries using MySQL:

```
1) SELECT atn_nid, atn_select_flag, atn_image_name
FROM city, attraction WHERE cty_nid = atn_cty_nid AND cty_nid = 5;

2) SELECT atn_nid, s2a_image_select_flag, atn_image_name 
FROM segment, seg2atn, attraction WHERE seg_nid = s2a_seg_nid AND
s2a_atn_nid = atn_nid and seg_nid = 68 AND
s2a_image_select_flag = true;
```

Note: The atn_select_flag in Query 1 and the s2a_image_select_flag are both Boolean

Since MYSQL for some reason does not support INTERSECT, I am at a loss as to the syntax to use to accomplish this.  Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume correctly that:

- fields named `atn_...`, `cty_...`, `seg_...`, and `s2a_...` belong to `attraction`, `city`, `segment`, and `seg2atn`, respectively.
- fields named `..._nid` are primary keys.
- `atn_cty_nid`, `s2a_seg_nid`, etc., are foreign keys.

then your first query is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT atn_nid, atn_select_flag, atn_image_name
  FROM attraction
 WHERE aty_cty_nid = 5
;
```

and your second query is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT atn_nid, TRUE, atn_image_name
  FROM attraction
 WHERE atn_id IN
        ( SELECT s2a_atn_nid
            FROM seg2atn
           WHERE s2a_seg_nid = 68
             AND s2a_image_select_flag = TRUE
        )
;
```

so their intersection is this:

```
SELECT atn_nid, TRUE AS atn_select_flag, atn_image_name
  FROM attraction
 WHERE atn_cty_nid = 5
   AND atn_nid IN
        ( SELECT s2a_atn_nid
            FROM seg2atn
           WHERE s2a_seg_nid = 68
             AND s2a_image_select_flag = TRUE
        )
;
```

and *(edited to add)* their union is this:

```
SELECT atn_nid, atn_select_flag, atn_image_name
  FROM attraction
 WHERE aty_cty_nid = 5
UNION
SELECT atn_nid, TRUE, atn_image_name
  FROM attraction
 WHERE atn_id IN
        ( SELECT s2a_atn_nid
            FROM seg2atn
           WHERE s2a_seg_nid = 68
             AND s2a_image_select_flag = TRUE
        )
;
```

Comment: ruakh, This works if you change seg_nid to s2a_seg_nid in the intersection. Thanks!! Unfortunately, being a novice, I just realized that I need the UNION of the two queries preserving the atn_select flag from the first query and the s2a_image_select_flag from the second (in a single column) in the result.  Can this be done?

Comment: @all4one: Re: `seg_nid` vs. `s2a_seg_nid`: Oops, you're right. Re: `UNION`: MySQL *does* support `UNION`, so yes. I'll update my answer.